# Detect Bot and Spam traffic on clicks?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, filtering, spam

I would like to track a few statistics about my webpage. So far I programmed the code for storing a click in my database if a user hits a button. This button calls a javascript function which is transfering the click via Ajax and PHP to MySQL.

But I would like to filter this traffic now. I only want to store and track the clicks by traffic which is from real users and not from bots, fake traffic or spam traffic...

Do you have any idea how to filter this traffic?

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, I think you are looking for Google Analytic. It can do what you want and much more.

Comment: No, I am not! Because I HAVE TO track it by my own! (Those datas are going to be used to create invoices!)

Comment: Chill dude! It was only a suggestion

Comment: I chill hahah... :)